# parallelize n-ary tree traversal using MPI

Tags: tree, mpi

I have generated an **n-ary tree** using the functions of glib in C. Now i need to parallelize the traversal in n-ary tree using MPI. I want to know if it is possible to parallelize tree traversal using MPI. If it is possible please suggest me how could I actually do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible but it may not be worth the effort.  I'll try to explain.  You may regard this as an extended comment if you wish, I'm certainly not proposing a solution, just a bunch of things to think about.

MPI processes are, essentially, separate instances of the same program and they each have their own address space populated (or not) with variables and data structures and so forth.  One hurdle you have to overcome to parallelise your traversal program is, therefore, to transfer data from (usually the) master process (where the tree is intially) to a set of worker processes.  One choice you have to make is whether to send the whole tree to all processes or only those parts of the tree which each worker process is to traverse.  This imposes a cost in terms of development effort (writing the code to figure out how to split the tree across processes, sending the chunks out, getting results back) and in execution time (communications take time but don't advance the computation at all).

Another hurdle to get over is that of pointers; I presume that you have used pointers to implement your serial algorithm since they seem to be popular with C programmers.  The trouble is that pointers from one MPI process are useless on another MPI process.  A pointer is, at root, just a reference to a memory address; there is no guarantee either that a pointer points to the same bit of data on another process, not even that it points to a valid memory location.  To overcome this you will have to serialise your tree in some way, pass across the serialised version and deserialise it on the worker process. (More execution time wasted in comparison to the serial version.)

This overhead, of splitting the tree into chunks and of serialising a pointer-based data structure, is what makes me doubt whether the effort to parallelise the program will be rewarded by performance improvements.

An alternative, worth considering if the tree is huge, would be to have each worker process read its own part of the tree from a disk file to which you have previously stored it, serialising as you did so.  So long as you coordinate the reading of the tree by multiple processes this will work.  Again, I'm not convinced, without data, that the effort would be worth making.

Another issue with parallelising programs on trees is that naive distributions of parts of a tree often result in poor load-balancing at run time.  Suppose you have a tree with a root with N children, and N+1 processes.  By all means send 1 child to each of N worker processes, but that is, for trees in general, not likely to lead to each child having an (approximately) equal amount of work to do.

Of course, if you have had the foresight to create a tree without using pointers, and to know that a naive splitting at level 1 or 2 in the tree will produce equally balanced sub-trees, your problem is much much simpler than the more general and pointer-based case.

Rather than MPI you might care to consider OpenMP, which is for parallel computing on shared memory computers.  A lot of the problems I see you facing using MPI would not exist if you were writing a shared memory program.